# How to add Youtube Video Image to Blog?

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube, blogs

I want to add a clickable YouTube video's image to my blog. I used the following code:

```
if (vidid == ""){
    var imgvid ="<a href='" + pURL + "#post-title" + "' title='" + pTITLE + "'>"
        + '<img class="no-thumbnail" src="img.youtube.com/vi/undefined/default.jpg"; />'
        + "</a>";
}else{
    var imgvid ="<a href='" + pURL + "#post-title" + "' title='" + pTITLE + "'>"
        + '<span class="play-button"></span><img class="'+ vidid
        + '" src="img.youtube.com/vi/'+vidid
        + '/default.jpg"; width="196px" height="147px"/>' + "</a>";
};
div.innerHTML = imgvid + '<div class="truncated-title"><h2>'
    + post_URL+'</h2></div>';
}
```

But it's not working. How can I resolve this?

Comment: That will put HTML code into a string variable, yes. Do you output it into the web page? How does the HTML code compare to what you want it to be?

Comment: I am new i cant understand please explain?

Comment: Your code sets the value of a variable named `imgvid`. Where is this code? Do you do anything with the contents of the `imgvid` variable afterwards?

Comment: if (vidid == ""){var imgvid ="<a href='" + pURL + "#post-title" + "' title='" + pTITLE + "'>" +'<img class="no-thumbnail" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/undefined/default.jpg" />' + "</a>";
 }else{
 var imgvid ="<a href='" + pURL + "#post-title" + "' title='" + pTITLE + "'>" + '<span class="play-button"></span><img class="'+ vidid +'" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+vidid+'/default.jpg" width="196px" height="147px"/>' + "</a>";
 };
 div.innerHTML = imgvid + '<div class="truncated-title"><h2>'+ post_URL+'</h2></div>';
}

Comment: I edited that code into your question. Whenever you want to add more information to your question, you can edit it with the ["edit" link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30859192/edit) below your question itself.

Comment: Could you explain what happens when you view your page in the web browser? Does the `post_URL` title display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using the YouTube integration API? You can get some more info in the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) and [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=de). Using it that way, Youtube will automatically generate and show the preview image, player controls etc.

Additionally, there might already be an extension for showing Youtube Videos on your blog - do you use Wordpress or a different standard Blogging platform?

**Edit**

Now that I know you are using Blogger - you should be able to add the youtube video to any post by default, please refer to [this manual](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/67428?hl=en) for details.